# How can I pivot a table and get the percentage of each row in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with a few rows, being each one a different subgroup from a major group, just like this:

```
group    subgroup    count
A        aaa         10
A        bbb         20
A        ccc         30
B        aaa         10
B        bbb         20
```

How can I pivot this table and get the percentage of each subgroup?
Basically, I want to get this:

```
group    subgroup_aaa    subgroup_bbb    subgroup_ccc
A        0.1666          0.33333         0.5
B        0.3333          0.5             0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try `crosstab` with `normalize`

```
s=pd.crosstab(index=df.group,columns=df.subgroup,values=df['count'],
              normalize='index',aggfunc='sum').\
              add_prefix('subgroup_').reset_index()
Out[476]: 
subgroup group  subgroup_aaa  subgroup_bbb  subgroup_ccc
0            A      0.166667      0.333333           0.5
1            B      0.333333      0.666667           0.0
```